# Do I need apple MFI program to access sms of IOS device through usb cable?

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I make a C# application for sms backup.
I want to access SMS/MMS of IOS device through usb cable to perform a backup.

I don't want to install anything on the device.

I see the apple's MFI program. https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-1

The available technology that I want is  "iPod Accessory Protocol (iAP), the protocol used to communicate with iPhone, iPad and iPod"

Do I need that MFI program ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at idevicebackup2? It's part of libimobiledevice, and allows you to take backups of iOS devices. I'd guess these backups also contain the SMS/MMS messages stored on the device.

Answer (score 0):

iAP doesn't provide sms related method.
I would suggest using bluetooth profile connection.
If using USB, you should create iOS APP to access sms and create your data format format protocol. Then, transfer data though USB iAP External Accessory protocol session to PC or other accessory.